# PDFBox PrintImageLocations

Tags: java, image, pdfbox

the expample programm works in most cases as expecte. But I constructed a PDF document with MS Word, that contains rotated images (0,90,180,270). The images are rotated within MS Word. The docx is exported to PDF. If I use the ImageBuild

The rotation is printed correct on the console. The tool saves original and transformed images. In this case, the original images (that should be saved as displayed) have the correct orientation - without rotation, whereas saved transformed images, that should have the right orientation, have got the orientation displayed in the PDF. It seems, that theres is a transformation within the PDF (image or document) that is not taken into concern.

```
Processing page: 1
*******************************************************************
Found image [Image9] 752a5115-bada-456a-abc9-0fe639b0f1c6.jpg
roation in PDF is : 0.0 degrees 
position in PDF = 56.7, 342.24 in user space units
raw image size  = 275, 183 in pixels
displayed size  = 206.25, 137.25 in user space units
displayed size  = 2.8645833, 1.90625 in inches at 72 dpi rendering
displayed size  = 72.760414, 48.41875 in millimeters at 72 dpi rendering

Processing page: 2
*******************************************************************
Found image [Image12] 71a5d04e-0ea5-4473-acab-b5365e8ac732.jpg
roation in PDF is : -90.0 degrees 
position in PDF = 56.7, 501.98 in user space units
raw image size  = 275, 183 in pixels
displayed size  = 206.25, 137.25 in user space units
displayed size  = 2.8645833, 1.90625 in inches at 72 dpi rendering
displayed size  = 72.760414, 48.41875 in millimeters at 72 dpi rendering

Processing page: 3
*******************************************************************
Found image [Image15] 89d80fc0-eadb-4afa-988b-318dc46c36b0.jpg
roation in PDF is : 180.0 degrees 
position in PDF = 262.95, 524.47 in user space units
raw image size  = 275, 183 in pixels
displayed size  = -206.25, -137.25 in user space units
displayed size  = -2.8645833, -1.90625 in inches at 72 dpi rendering
displayed size  = -72.760414, -48.41875 in millimeters at 72 dpi rendering

Processing page: 4
*******************************************************************
Found image [Image15] a3d051f7-7ee2-4f47-9027-0c42be23839c.jpg
roation in PDF is : 90.0 degrees 
position in PDF = 193.95, 295.73 in user space units
raw image size  = 275, 183 in pixels
displayed size  = 206.25, 137.25 in user space units
displayed size  = 2.8645833, 1.90625 in inches at 72 dpi rendering
displayed size  = 72.760414, 48.41875 in millimeters at 72 dpi rendering
```

Comment: please share the PDF.

Comment: See [PDFBOX-5179](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-5179)